# How can I use two variable power supplies to get to a specific current and voltage?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, current-source

I am trying to power a laser that requires 87 volts at 3 amps but I only have two variable power supplies can provide 60 volts 5 amps and 112 volts 1.7 amps (nonstandard value because it's not working at full capacity anymore). Is there any way to use them in combination (parallel or series),with resistors or in a simple circuit to get to the voltage and amps that it needs(without overloading the laser)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 1):

No. Parallel will be limited to 60 V, series will be limited to 1.7 A.

You have enough power there though, so you could use a DC-DC converter to convert the output of one into something that could be combined with the other.